# how can i interpret this code?(related to trim)

Tags: excel, vba

I don't know how to interpret code below

```
If Cells(iRow, iCol).Cells.Count = 1 And Trim(Cells(iRow, iCol)) <> "" Then
```

I cannot understand after "and trim~". Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: It's to test if the cell holds any value other than an empty string after leading/trailing spaces are trimmed.

Comment: Thanks, what does <>"" means here?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question shows no research was done on ttthe Trim statement

Comment: Further notes: 1) a `Cells.Count` check for the condition `=1`executed upon a **single** cell is a redundant check as it will be always true. 2) Furthermore I'd fully qualify any range references as without explicit reference to a workbook's sheet, VBA assumes the currently active one, and this needn't be the one you have in mind. @howto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Trim function removes spaces in the beginning and end, so in English `Trim(Cells(iRow, iCol)) <> ""` would be something like remove the spaces before and after and check if the result is different than an empty string. In VBA `<>` means 'not equal to' and `""` is an empty string.

Personally I would use `Trim(Cells(iRow, iCol).Value) <> ""` just to make sure that VBA is looking at the cell's contents.